# Unchecking box and modifying grand total - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reverse my grand price upon item removal. Currently, when i remove an item, i set `grand total to 0`.

If i have

```
benz - 150

bmw -  100  //with quantity of 2 meaning bmw price is 50

total  - 250
```

but when i remove bmw from the list,

i should be getting something like this

```
benz - 150

total - 150
```

How can i achieve this by reversing the grand price to the previous price when item is deselected?

```js
function calc(goods) {

  var product = JSON.parse(goods.dataset.goods);
  if (goods.checked == true) {
    $('.panel').append(
      '<div class="container"> ' +
      '<p  class="name" >' + product.name + '</p>' +
      '<p  class="price" data-price="' + product.price + '">' + product.price + '</p>' +
      '<p class="total" ><span class="sub-total" name="sub-total" id="sub-total"></span></p>' +
      '<input  type="text" class="form-control quantity"  placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/>' +
      '</div>'
    )
  } else {
    $(".panel .container [data-id=" + product.id + "]").parent().remove();
    $('.mygoods span').text(0);
  }
}

$('.panel').on('keyup', '.quantity', function() {
  var container = $(this).closest('div');
  var quantity = Number($(this).val());
  var price =
    Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));

  container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
  sum = 0;

  $(".sub-total").each(function() {
    sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
  })

  $('.mygoods span').text(sum);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="mygoods">GrandTotal <span></span></p>
</div>

<input onclick="return calc(this)" data-good="{{$good->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" />
```

When i deselect an item, old text is always 0 even if i add up the total
**Update**

```
 function calc(goods) {

  var product = JSON.parse(goods.dataset.goods);
  if (goods.checked == true) {
    $('.panel').append(
      '<div class="container"> ' +
      '<p  class="name" >' + product.name + '</p>' +
      '<p  class="price" data-price="' + product.price + '">' + product.price + '</p>' +
      '<p class="total" ><span class="sub-total" name="sub-total" id="sub-total"></span></p>' +
      '<input  type="text" class="form-control quantity"  placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/>' +
      '</div>'
    )
  } else {
    var total = $(".panel .container [data-id=" + product.id + "]").parent().find(".total").text();

    $(".panel .container [data-id=" + product.id + "]").parent().remove();

 if (total) {
        $('.mygoods span').text(function(oldtext) {
            console.log('this is my old text '+oldtext)
            return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;

        });
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: please create a working model

Comment: @brk, i am new to creating snippets

Comment: Why don't you just subtract the price of the item you're removing from the total?

Comment: @Barmar, the price of the item would differ when the quantity is not 1. So if i subtract the price of the item being removed, there could be an issue since the quantity is a factor

Comment: In the example you showed, the price of `bmw` is `100`, and you want the total to be reduced by `100`. However `100` is calculated, that's what you want to subtract.

Comment: @Barmar i just edited my code. please look at the comment beside the bmw

Comment: It doesn't matter how you got `100`, just subtract that from the total.

Comment: @Barmar any errors in my update

Comment: Sorry, getting ready to leave for vacation, I don't have any more time for this.

Comment: @Barmar, you should always complete what you start :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you remove the element with the subtotal for that product, get the text of the `.total span` element, then subtract it from the grand total.

```
  } else {
    var total = $(".panel .container [data-id=" + product.id + "]").parent().find(".total").text();
    $(".panel .container [data-id=" + product.id + "]").parent().remove();
    if (total) {
        $('.mygoods span').text(function(oldtext) {
            return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: oldtext is always 0 when i console it.. Why is that happening ?

Comment: `oldtext` should be whatever is already in the Grand Total. Have you added to the total yet?

Comment: Yes i have added total. How do you actually  get your oldtext?  I am trying to see how it is related to the grand total

Comment: `oldtext` is the current grand total. When you uncheck an item, it gets subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

Pure js approach;

```js
window.onload = assignEventListener();

function assignEventListener() {
let allCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
let grandTotal = 0;
   for(i=0;i<allCheckBoxes.length;i++) {
      allCheckBoxes[i].onchange = function() {
       checkedBoxesSum(allCheckBoxes,grandTotal);
      }     
   }   
}

function checkedBoxesSum(allCheckBoxes,grandTotal) {
 //let allChecked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
 for(i=0;i<allCheckBoxes.length;i++) {
  if(allCheckBoxes[i].checked == true) {  
      grandTotal += parseInt(allCheckBoxes[i].getAttribute('value'));
  }
}
 document.getElementById("Grandtotal").innerHTML = "GrandTotal is "+ grandTotal
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="bmw" value="150"/> BMW
<input type="checkbox" id="mercedes" value="300"/> Mercedes
<input type="checkbox" id="audi" value="400"/> Audi
<div id="Grandtotal">

</div>
```

Comment: This is would have been very simple for me to achieve but with mine, the user enters the quantity as well. The value is not fixed like what you have in yours

Comment: this is why we insist on a snippet to get a clear idea before starting, no matter how much you put in words, seeing a working snippet saves a lot of energy and time.. anyways the user enters value and how is it stored to checkbox?

Comment: i don't store value to checkbox but i try to retrieve it in the loop

Comment: You lost me; pls elaborate clearly; there is an input box; there are three checkboxes and....